# oracle auto increment to primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, auto-increment

there is a table in oracle. it has primary key but withought identity(auto increment).
there are projects insert  new records to this table(about 5-6row in every second).
my question is that, how can i change the primary key to auto increment

Comment: See [**Auto-increment primary key in Pre 12c releases**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/) and [**IDENTITY column autoincrement functionality in Oracle 12c**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `SEQUENCE` it will increment the values automatically.

Refer [SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm)